# How can I save a tag value in an entry in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I am working on a plugin and I have the following code

```
private function _tagProducts(array $products, array $names)
{
    foreach ($products as $productId)
    {
        $product = Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementById($productId, Product::class, null);
        $product['businessTag'] = ['something'];
        $product['purchasedWithVoucher'] = 'no';
        Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($product);
    }
}
```

If I remove/comment out the line `$product['businessTag'] = ['something'];` this snippet runs just fine and updates the field `purchasedWithVoucher` just fine. But, if I keep the `businessTag` line in I get the following error.

`(Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException)`

I have tried updating the tag field as `$product['businessTag'] = 'something';` which at least throws no errors, but the product is not updated with the new tag, however the `$product['purchasedWithVoucher'];` line does update so I know that simply saving the changes isn't the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is that Tags are also elements, so you'll need to save them or look them up to assign them. Something like this:

```
    public function createOrGetTag($keyword, $groupId) {
        $tagQuery = new TagQuery(Tag::class);
        $tagQuery->groupId = $groupId;
        $tagQuery->title = $keyword;
        $tag = $tagQuery->one();

        if (!$tag) {
            $tag = new Tag();
            $tag->groupId = $groupId;
            $tag->title = $keyword;
            Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($tag);
        }

        return $tag;
    }
```

And then in your field setting, you'd do something like this:

```
$product->businessTag->id[] = $tag->id;
```

Comment: Sorry about all the comments and deleted comments. I had done something wrong and messed up the code when I put it in and it didn't work, then found a solution I thought worked but only made a mess. I still am though, stuck on the last line `$product->businessTag->id[] = $tag->id;` it successfully updates the product with the tag but it overwrites all other tags.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with Ransom Roberson code `$product->businessTag->id[] = $tag->id;` but otherwise everything else worked. The problem is the snippet above will update the tag and then overwrite every tag the entry/product has. So I wrote the code below. Ransom's code works perfectly aside from the last part, so putting this with it should help anyone in the future who is might struggle with this.

```
$existingTags = $product->businessTag->ids();

    foreach ($existingTags as $eTag)
    {
        $product->businessTag->id[] = $eTag;
    }

    $product->businessTag->id[] = $tag->id
```